# NSURL Query String Noob

Tags: alamofire

I am needing to make this query: `/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_CAD"`

I've partially figured out how to use parameters: `["instruments" : "EUR_USD"]` which gets me the first part of the query. I am having a difficult time getting to the second part.

My issue is getting `%2C` added to the query. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%2C` is the URL encoding for `,`.

So `["instruments" : "EUR_USD,USD_CAD"]` will probably do what you want.